# Why does PySpark casts/converts when comparing columns of different types?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

## TL;DR

When using `filter` and comparing values in different columns that have different data types, PySpark casts the values implicitly. This can lead to some unexpected results. See the details below.

The question is why does it behave this way? This behavior has serious side effects as discussed below.

## Observations

Consider the following dataframe:

```py
cols = StructType([
    StructField('ints', IntegerType()),
    StructField('doubles', DoubleType()),
    StructField('strings', StringType()),
])
data = [
    [1, 1.0, "1"],
    [1, 1.2, "1.2"],
    [1, 1.2, "1.3"],
    [1, 1.2, "some string"]
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)
```

Next, consider the following comparisons.

### INTs vs DOUBLEs

```py
df.withColumn("int = doubles", F.col("ints") == F.col("doubles"))
```

returns:

```
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+
|ints|doubles|    strings|int = doubles|
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+
|   1|    1.0|          1|         true|
|   1|    1.2|        1.2|        false|
|   1|    1.2|        1.3|        false|
|   1|    1.2|some string|        false|
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

This kind of make sense, the numerical value `1` and `1.0`, from a mathematical stand point, are the same. One may argue that from a data perspective they are different though...

### DOUBLEs vs STRINGs

Here we compare:

```py
df.withColumn("double = string", F.col("doubles") == F.col("strings"))
```

which returns:

```
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+
|ints|doubles|    strings|double = string|
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+
|   1|    1.0|          1|           true|
|   1|    1.2|        1.2|           true|
|   1|    1.2|        1.3|          false|
|   1|    1.2|some string|           null|
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

From a mathematical perspective it's fine.

### INTs vs STRINGs

Here it goes a little troubling. Comparing:

```py
df.withColumn("int = string", F.col("ints") == F.col("strings"))
```

returns:

```
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
|ints|doubles|    strings|int = string|
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
|   1|    1.0|          1|        true|
|   1|    1.2|        1.2|        true|
|   1|    1.2|        1.3|        true|
|   1|    1.2|some string|        null|
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
```

So, the integer `1`, as far as Spark is concerned, equals the double `1.2`!!

## How does it happen?

It turns out (try to append `.explain(True)` to the lines above, that PySpark casts/converts the types of the columns before comparing them:

- INTs vs. DOUBLEs: the integers as casted to doubles
- DOUBLEs vs. STRINGs: the strings are converted to doubles
- INTs vs. STRINGs: again, the strings are converted, this time to **integers**!

## WHY??

Why does PySpark is doing this? What is the mathematical/logical reasoning behind this? This behavior can have very unexpected side effects when trying to join data. For example, consider:

```py
cols = StructType([
    StructField('ints', IntegerType()),
    StructField('values', StringType()),
])
data = [
    [1, "foo"],
    [1, "bar"],
    [1, "goo"],
    [1, "loo"]
]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)
```

and

```py
cols = StructType([
    StructField('strings', StringType()),
    StructField('values2', StringType()),
])
data = [
    ["1.0", "foo2"],
    ["1.2", "bar2"],
    ["1.3", "goo2"],
    ["some string", "loo2"]
]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)
```

Then, the result of: `df1.join(df2, df1.ints == df2.strings, how="left")` is:

```
+----+------+-------+-------+
|ints|values|strings|values2|
+----+------+-------+-------+
|   1|   foo|    1.3|   goo2|
|   1|   foo|    1.2|   bar2|
|   1|   foo|    1.0|   foo2|
|   1|   bar|    1.3|   goo2|
|   1|   bar|    1.2|   bar2|
|   1|   bar|    1.0|   foo2|
|   1|   goo|    1.3|   goo2|
|   1|   goo|    1.2|   bar2|
|   1|   goo|    1.0|   foo2|
|   1|   loo|    1.3|   goo2|
|   1|   loo|    1.2|   bar2|
|   1|   loo|    1.0|   foo2|
+----+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: You should always explicitly cast your columns if you want to compare columns of different data type. What would you expect to be the correct behaviour?

Comment: @RobertKossendey First I would not want Spark to tell me that `1` equals `"1.2"`. There is too much hidden logic here that can easily lead to problems. The  behavior I  would expect is one where if both data types are numerical, then they will be casted and compared according to mathematical logic. On the other hand, a numerical and non-numerical should always be non-equal. This is how Pandas is doing it (see the bottom [here](https://gist.github.com/drorata/2d2e4f145996337e042d71f3d101f14a)).

Comment: I could also live with a logic that first checks the types and if they're different then the values are not equal.

Comment: this might not be what you want but check this config. `.config("spark.sql.ansi.enabled", "true")`?   this will crash when you try to compare strings to numeric.  There could be other options here than the generic `enabled` flag that you could try  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-ansi-compliance.html

Comment: @Emma This is exactly the direction I was looking for! Thanks! It's not yet a complete answer :) but it's a start. For the sake of future visitors here are the [docs with @v3.4.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/sql-ref-ansi-compliance.html).